# Search Functionality for ASP.NET Ecommerce Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, search, e-commerce

I have an Ecommerce/Online Shopping site with 20 Subpages. It has various products and i want to implement a search functionality for it. The search could be anything like "White shirt" , "Black Shoes", "Leather Belt" so on.

How do i implement the search mechanism ? The site is expected to grow in years.

I know solutions like SQL free-text, Full-text search, Lucene.Net, Lucene.NET solr , ElasticSearch.

but which one would be appropriate for the scenario. You know people search weird things ?

Comment: Did you build your own ecommerce?

Comment: Yes..@Oskar , Online shopping only garments. I have categories like Men, Women..I want search results based on categories..for example have a search here www.flipkart.com

Comment: I would use Full-Text search if you're already using SQL for search logic.

Comment: Did you get the answer for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using LinQ, you can use statements like:

```
var _searchWord = myTextbox.Test;
myContainer.All.Where(s => s.mysearchcriteria.Contains(_searchWord));
```